# Laravel 5.2 updated table now model wont work

Tags: php, laravel

I updated my notes table with 4 new columns: classification, pod, sampled, followup.

I would update my model like so (which still works like this):

```
$note->account_id       = $account->id;
$note->name             = $request->input('account-note-title');
$note->description      = $request->input('account-note-description');
$note->save();
```

But if I try and post to the new columns it fails.

```
$note->account_id       = $account->id;
$note->name             = $request->input('account-note-title');
$note->description      = $request->input('account-note-description');
$note->classification   = $request->input('account-note-classification');
$note->pod              = $request->input('account-note-pod');
$note->sampled          = $request->input('account-note-samplebrand');
$note->followup         = $request->input('account-note-followup-date');
$note->save();
```

Do I have to refresh the model or anything?

Comment: what is the error shown?

Comment: My php console isnt logging any errors

Comment: are you enabling the debug mode? how is your table in database, reflect your migration?

Comment: How do I enable debug mode? It just stated working so I think it was actually an error in my validation I forgot I changed

Comment: if you are using .env, just change `APP_DEBUG=true`. if not you should check in `config/app.php`

Comment: Does it actually throw an error or do the columns just not update?

Comment: have you changed your model file

Comment: in Model Note.php check if $fillable contains 'account_id, name, description'

Comment: Please show your migration and model files.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new value using laravel Create methode like below
ModelName::create($request->all())
In this case you have to put your all input field in the $fillable variable of MODEL.
You can update item using the following method
$model = findOrFail($id)
$model->update($request->all())